# sync templatedParent property with control template item property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Using WPF I'm trying to bind Text property of TextBox to Text property of custom control. Could anyone tell me how to achieve that?

Firstly I have template for control which contains TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_InputTextBox" 
    Text="[???]">
</TextBox>
```

My custom control which uses this template contains DependencyProperty "Text"

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(AutocompleteSelector), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

My question is: What binding I should use (instead of [???]) in Text property of TextBox, to get two way sync of these properties? I mean that, when CustomControl.Text would be changed I want to change TextBox.Text too and vice-versa. I've tried already

```
{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: does it work if you set the Binding to `{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:AutocompleteSelector}}}` where `local` is the namespace alias where `AutocompleteSelector` resides?

Comment: @Viv - unfortunately no. Maybe I should use TextChanged event handler to push TextBox.Text value to AutocompleteSelector.Text property? I'd prefer Binding solution, but if there's no one...

Comment: well then the issue is not with the binding, from the code you've posted it ain't easy to figure out what could be the issue, I could only say try removing the name `PART_InputTextBox` from the `TextBox` and try with the binding I'd posted in the previous comment to see if that works, failing that post the full xaml for the control or put together a sample that would reproduce the issue and attach it to your question.